# Get number of objects in a Core Data relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a tableview with recipe. The user can add and remove recipe. 
When a recipe is clicked, another tableview is pushed, and display the ingredients. Same here, the user can add and remove ingredients.

There is a oneToMany relationship between recipe and ingredients.

I want to display the number of ingredient in the recipe tableview row. I know how to set it all up in interface builder with the rows, but I dont know how to get the count of ingredient for a single recipe.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

Use countForFetchRequest instead of executeFetchRequest and (for SQL backed stores) it will do a COUNT instead of a SELECT.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using core data you can just ask the ingredients list how many ingredients it has inside it by calling the count method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int count = [recipe.ingredients count];
    return count;
}
```

You can find out what properties and methods the collection class has by looking at the [NSSet class in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I found out what class to look at by looking at the generated class that core data creates:

```
@class ParentObject;
@interface ParentObject :  NSManagedObject  
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* childObjects;
@end
```

Comment: Since the OP already has the recipe object this is the easiest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a fetch for all the ingredients, with a predicate that allows all matches. This `NSFetchRequest` will return an `NSArray`, when executed. Just do a `[myArray count]` to get the number of ingredients.

Comment: Isnt that too much work ( object creation  ect) just for getting the count ?

Comment: Perhaps there are other ways to get to the data store without creating any objects. Please post alternatives. I'm curious myself.

Comment: Actually, here's a SO question on the very subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-coredata-effiecient-way-to-count-entities

Comment: Since the Recipe object is already in memory, the easiest path is to ask the relationship for its count as mentioned by Helephant above.