# Core Data: Count across relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios

I have three models:

```
+----------+        +--------------+        +------+
| Occasion | <--->> | GiftOccasion | <--->> | Gift |
+----------+        +--------------+        +------+
```

I've like to get the name of the occasion, and a count of all the gifts that meet certain criteria. Currently I'm getting the distinct list of occasions sorted by year and name:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request retain];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"year", nil]];    
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

NSSortDescriptor *yearDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"year" ascending:NO selector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yearDescriptor, nameDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:descriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

... but I'm totally stumped as to how to get the count of `Gift`. Is there a straightforward way, or do I need to traverse each `GiftOccasion` and related `Gift`s and add it all together?

ETA: Note that I'm **generating distinct results**, here, not getting the model directly. I assume I'd have to run another request to get this information, but if it's possible not to, that would be better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Get number of objects in a Core Data relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512483/get-number-of-objects-in-a-core-data-relationship)

Comment: Right, but I'm going through another relationship on the way. Do I need to manually iterate through `GiftOccasion` and add up the count of `Gift` for each? Is there actually not a better way? Also, I'm using `setReturnsDistinctResults:YES`, which is a problem as well.

Comment: Alternatively you can use @count with the data key path to get the count as well. then you don't need to iterate through the middle part

Comment: Nevin, how exactly could we get the count using a key value collection operator here?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good answer, and I'm not going to select it as the "right" answer, but what I ended up doing was a ridiculous set of nested `NSEnumerator`s that go through each relationship and eventually do a `count += 1;`, something like this:

```
    NSUInteger giftCount = 0;


    NSEnumerator *oEnum = [resultsList objectEnumerator];
    Occasion *occasion = nil;
    while (occasion = [oEnum nextObject]) {

        NSEnumerator *goEnum = [occasion.giftOccasions objectEnumerator];
        GiftOccasion *go;

        while (go = [goEnum nextObject]) {
            if (go.gifts) {

                NSEnumerator *giftEnum = [go.gifts objectEnumerator];
                Gift *gift = nil;
                while (gift = [giftEnum nextObject]) {
                    NSLog(@"Gift: %@ %@", gift.name, gift.purchased);
                    if ([gift.purchased boolValue] == NO) {
                        giftCount += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Embarrassing, but it works. :-)

If there is a better, more efficient way to do this, I'd love to hear it. It's one of the things I dislike about Core Data as an ORM vs., say, ActiveRecord.