# iphone, get the object count without performing a fetch?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I seem to recall that it's possible to return the resulting object count from an NSPredicate in CoreData without actually performing a fetch, but I can't find any reference to this.

Can someone confirm that I wasn't dreaming (sad dream to have!), and would this be safe to do in another thread?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-effiecient-way-to-count-entities/1134353#1134353) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-effiecient-way-to-count-entities).  You just need to add your predicate to the fetch request in the provided code.

Comment: [moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];

Great, thanks very much