# Getting a count of records in a core data entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Does anyone know of an existing function or property that provides a count of the records in a Core Data entity?

Comment: Here is the solution for lately comers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-efficient-way-to-count-entities/36906545#36906545

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the best way to accomplish this is through NSManagedObjectContext's [`countForFetchRequest:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-countforfetchrequest?language=objc)

It works just like a regular fetch request, except that it only returns the count and presumably could therefore be more optimized.

Comment: It is definitely more optimized.

Comment: @Marcus: Yeah, the reason I hedged there is simply because I haven't used all the backing stores and it's possible that there'd be one where there's no shortcut available for the count.

Comment: Count is always more efficient even on an xml store (the least performant store) because it is not constructing objects as a result of the fetch.

Comment: Looks like link is broken. Can you please update it?

Comment: @Vishal I just did.  But you can edit old posts to do that, too! It's just [a google search away…](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=NSManagedObjectContext%20countForFetchRequest%20error).

Answer (score 14):

```
   func getRecordsCount() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: _entityName)
        do {
            let count = try context.count(for: fetchRequest)
            print(count)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way of getting numberofdata is

```
func getNumberofData(){
        let userFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSNumber>(entityName: "entityName")

        userFetchRequest.resultType = .countResultType
        do {

            let counts: [NSNumber] = try! context.fetch(userFetchRequest)
            let count = counts[0]
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the more modern and efficient way, as recommended in WWDC '20 video "Core Data: Sundries and maxims". Thank you, user14185615.

Comment: I think the `do` block without a `catch` is a bit confusing, so I'd suggest adding one, even if it just contains a comment for the sort of thing the coder should fill in. Then the contents of the `do` block, I'd suggest you simplify to: `let count = try context.fetch(userFetchRequest).first!`