# Return row count from coredata (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to pass some images in a `UITableView` which is saved to coredata, to a `UICollectionView` , which is not a part of coredata.

I want the return count of `numberOfItemsInsection` of `UICollectionView` should be equal to total row count of `UITableView` .
How can I access the number of rows of `UITableView`?

Comment: Your question shouldn't be about UITableView and UICollectionView but about the data source(s) that you use for those UI components. So the number of rows of the UITableView is the `count` property of the array you use as the data source for the table view. If you don't have access to the data source from where you want to do the comparison you need to execute a count fetch request, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184050/getting-a-count-of-records-in-a-core-data-entity) for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access tableview numberOfRows as:

```
    tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: [//Section No])
```

You can get numberOfRows from Coredata as:

```
func getRecordsCount() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: _entityName)
    do {
        let count = try context.count(for: fetchRequest)
        print(count)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```