# core data select count(*) from table differs from select * from table

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I've been using core data with iphone for a few months so far with no issue. I've created a new table and have copied some basic code from other classes into my new class that deletes all entries from the table and then loads the table again.

I'm using the following method to delete from the table:

```
-(void) deleteFromEntity
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MCCountry" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects) {
        [context deleteObject:object];
    }

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that the load process loads 271 rows. When I debug this delete method the fetchedObjects object contains 271 rows, and it then loops 271 times deleting it's way through.

Thing is that the table currently contains 1084 rows. So I ran select count(*) from zmccountry and it gives me 271 rows. 1084/271 is 4, so I've run this script 4 times and it doesn't appear to be deleting anything.

So question is:

1. Why does count(*) return a different row count to select *
2. Is there anything obviously wrong with this method (it's happily working elsewhere but if anyone spots anything let me know.

EDIT***

I've tried the following:

-recreate the table with the same name.
-recreate the table with a different name.
-rewrite the load process to more closely match one of my other files
-rewrite the load process to do a single entity load instead of a list

Only the last one seems to work, none of the others did. Still leaves me with the rest of the entities to load but making progress

**EDIT**
I've raised a bug with apple for this one, i'm not sure if somehow the database is getting corrupted but it's completely repeatable even after rewriting the class from scratch. Utterly bizarre.

Comment: Method looks pretty solid. You say that select * and count(\*) are coming back with different results, but you're saying that the load process loads 271 rows AND count(*) returns 271? Can you clarify?

Comment: the table load method loads in 271 records each time it's run. When i run select count(*) from table; it returns 271 records. When I run select * from table; I get 1084 records in the output

Comment: Can you [do a count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-efficient-way-to-count-entities) inside your delete method to see how many it's picking up?

Comment: How do you examine the total rows? Do you directly scan the .sqlite file with an sql editor? If so, I guess that core data dos not delete the rows in the sqlite table but will mark them as deleted in its supporting files.

Comment: NSLog(@" Deleted count of country %lu",(unsigned long)[fetchedObjects count]); gives me Deleted count of country 271. select count(*) still 271, whilst select * now 813 (i did a reset just to keep working)

Comment: i open up the database by getting the simulator file location and using sqlite3 "path/to/file/file.sqlite3". then i run select * from zmytablename. I've checked other tables and the records are actually fully deleted using this exact same function

Comment: What's the correlation between `zmccountry` and `MCCountry`?

Comment: :) me being lazy whilst typing. They are one and the same

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not logical at all. If you select all records from a table you should get back the number of records. It is impossible that they are different with the count method.

I suspect that your data is somehow corrupted (you might have run an initialization routine 4 times or something similar). I suggest you delete the app from the simulator (or reset the simulator) and try again from scratch. Monitor when and how often you do inserts into this table.

You might also first try to manually clean the table with `delete from zmccountry;`.

Comment: I agree with your statement completely. I've worked on databases for many years but only recently on core data and sqlite. I've tried rebuilding and resetting the simulator. In fact the only way to work currently is to do this between test runs otherwise the data gets corrupted. I'll try rebuilding i think