# How do I get a fetch request to return the number of objects in the persistent store?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

When my app launches and the first view controller is created, a new backing NSManagedObject is also created. At this point, I have NOT saved the context (and I started with a fresh, empty persistent store).

The user can transition to another screen that will show a message if there are no saved items or, if saved items exist, it will show a list of the items. This is how I'm checking for saved items:

```
func checkForSavedItems() -> Bool {
    var itemsDoExist = false
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSNumber>(entityName: "Items")
    fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
    fetchRequest.resultType = .countResultType

    do {
        let countResult = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        itemsDoExist = countResult.first!.intValue > 0
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
    return itemsDoExist
}
```

I expected that `fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false` would have ensured that the new object that hasn't been saved would not be counted but it is. The count comes back as 1 so it must be counting items in the `NSManagedObjectContext`

This also suggests that the fetch request is returning the count of items in the context, not the persistent store.

How do I get the real number of items in the persistent store?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`count(for: NSFetchRequest)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count)?

Comment: I had not, but I did now and that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Willeke - I think a small part of the solution is similar, but that's where the similarities end. The thread you think might be a duplicate is going on 10 years old, it's in Objective-C, and the OP was working with NSFetchedResultsController and asking for a more efficient way to get a 'count entities'. I'm specifically asking about how to get the count of entities in the store, not the context. It's also in Swift and doesn't introduce the complexity of the NSFetchedResultsController. I think my question will do more to help people with a similar question than that old post would.

Comment: @pbasdf - If you'll make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393288/4244136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also expected that `fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false` would exclude objects that have been inserted in the context but not saved to the store.

However, the `count(for: NSFetchRequest)` method should give the correct count.  You can find the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count).

Comment: your first paragraph is vague. Can you rephrase it? What did you expect? What did you see? Does `fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false` exclude objects?

Comment: `includesPendingChanges` does indeed work for that. Before I set this flag to true I was getting the count of unsaved objects as well. When it's set to false I only get objects actually saved to the store