# shape data from core data into plottable format

Tags: xcode, plot, core-data, swiftui

I have a conceptual question regarding plotting charts in SwiftUI based on data from core data.
Lets say I am building a todo list app and I have a todo entity in core data. This entity has the attributes name and finishDate (the date on which the todo was marked as finished).

To plot these two variables, I need a variable containing each individual day and a variable containing the number of finished tasks on each specific day.

Does anyone know how I would go about creating this data efficiently? I know I can fetch the todo entity data and select the correct attributes. But how do I get the number of finished tasks on each specific day? Ideally without creating those variables using for loops.

It would be really appreciated if anyone can help me.

Comment: You need to look into relationships in Core Data. Frankly, I will bet there are a great deal of Core Data tutorials that use a ToDo app as their basis, simply because it is obvious. Whether or not you do it the same way, you will at least familiarize yourself with the issues.

Comment: This is more if a database management thing vs a core data thing. Read up on database management. It is more about how your entity is structured. Once you have it structured it is about the sort descriptors, predicate, and maybe even the sections, you could have daily sections. Look up WWDC21 CoreData videos I think the one about concurrency talked about the sectioned fetch request

Answer (score 4):

This is easy using CoreData + SwiftUI.

The code below is for iOS15+ but you can do the same thing with an `NSFetchedResultsController` or `NSFetchRequest` / `@FetchRequest` and then group it. But it will require a bit of effort to stay real time.

Also, the code below is meant to work with the standard Apple code for a CoreData project. The only thing I changed in `PersistenceController` is setting a random day for the `timestamp`

```
newItem.timestamp = Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*Double(Int.random(in: -10...10)))
```

This is a simple graph

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct DayChart: View {
    @SectionedFetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sectionIdentifier: \.completionDate, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)], predicate: nil, animation: Animation.linear)
    var sections: SectionedFetchResults<String, Item>
    @State var maxCount: Int = 1
    let spacing: CGFloat = 3
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            GeometryReader{ geo in
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: spacing){
                    ForEach(sections){section in
                        VStack{
                            Text(section.count.description)
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .onAppear(){
                                    maxCount = max(maxCount,section.count)
                                    
                                }
                            Text(section.id.description).minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                        }.frame(width: (geo.size.width/CGFloat(sections.count) - spacing),height: geo.size.height * CGFloat(CGFloat(section.count)/CGFloat(maxCount)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(.leading, spacing)
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct DayChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DayChart().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
extension Item{
    //This is the variable that determines your section/column/completion date
    @objc
    var completionDate: String{
                    
        if self.timestamp != nil{
            let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd\nMMM"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: self.timestamp!)
             
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Nit: the implicit assumption that days are 24 hours long is incorrect (fails at DST transitions and across time zone changes). We have better Date API than using `addingTimeInterval(60*60*24…)`

Comment: @HalMueller Thanks. I don't usually do it like that. This was just for `Preview`. I was under the impression that `Date()` is a value that [encapsulates a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date values represent a time interval relative to an absolute reference date.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date). I am pretty sure it is in UTC. I don't think to would make much of a difference when creating a random date for an example or in most scenarios, especially since most of the methods and vars of `Date` are `TimeInterval`

Comment: I figured as much, and concur completely! Felt obliged to add the comment lest someone resort to caveman date math :)

Answer (score 0):

I’d start with an attribute for the day of the week (which you can derive from the `Date()` value you’re using for completion date). Then you can use either a count fetch request ([Cocoa Core Data efficient way to count entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-efficient-way-to-count-entities)), or a group-by and an `NSDictionaryResultType` (extensive code example at https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/04/group-by-count-and-sum-in-coredata/). The group-by approach will give you a dictionary that looks like this (from the Cocoanetics article):

```
[
   {
      "count": 111,
      "col": "One"
   },
   {
      "count": 222,
      "col": "Two"
   }
]
```

I believe, but don’t know for certain, that you’ll have to compute/store the day-of-week value as an attribute for these grouping approaches to work.