# How can I sort weekdays in coredata stored as a string

Tags: swift, date, core-data

Within my coredata I have an attribute `day` that is stored as a `String`.  I'm storing Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and so on.  Here's the portion of my code where I set my `fetchRequest` and `sortDescriptors`, but I'm not sure what needs to happen before or after to convert weekdays to be sortable.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Exercise_V2>(entityName: "Exercise_V2")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "day", ascending: true)]
```

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssortdescriptor) you see that you can create a sort descriptor that takes an argument where you can pass your own sorting logic, I would investigate that

Comment: It would help if you show us how your weekdays are defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121593/shape-data-from-core-data-into-plottable-format/69131192#69131192

Comment: @JoakimDanielson they're defined as a String and full spelling.

Comment: What does that mean? So they are not part of another type like an enum or an array?

Answer (score 0):

In CoreData try to save day in string along with dayID. e.g for Monday dayID will be 1, for Tuesday it will be 2 and so on.
And fetch the data with ascending order of dayID. You will get all the weekdays.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but when I sort by dayID I get all the days grouped together.