# SwiftUI: How to dynamically adjust ForEach elements?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a List() containing rows of expenses (from CoreData). Like this:

```
                            ForEach(expenses) { expense in
                                ExpenseRow(e:expense, cv: self)
                                }
```

Here’s the struct ExpenseRow:

```
struct ExpenseRow: View {
        var e: ExpenseEntry
        var cv: ContentView
        var body: some View {
            NavigationLink {
                NewExpenseCard(existingExpense:e)
            } label: {
                HStack{
                    Text(e.amount.description.abs() ?? " ")
                        .foregroundColor(e.amount < 0 ? .green : Color(UIColor.label))
                    Text(e.note ?? "")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    Spacer()
                                    
                    Text(shortDateString(date: e.timestamp!))
                        .padding(.all, 5)
                        .font(.body)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

So each row is an HStack of amount - note - date.

The date portion of the list now looks like this:

- Jan 1
- Jan 1
- Jan 2

Instead, I’d like a date only to be shown if it hasn’t been displayed previously, to avoid duplicate dates being shown. Like this:

- Jan 1
- 
- Jan 2

But I can’t find any way of doing this. I tried a state variable to track the last displayed date (Jan 1) and then only display the next one if it differs from this, but that leads to an infinite loop where Swift keeps going through the rows forever trying to update them.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Have you thought about using a `SectionedFetchRequest` to group your items by date? You could then either use a `Section` view per day and put the date in the section header, or loop through the sections to build a single-section list and only display the date if the expense is the first item in the section…

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384263/grouping-coredata-by-date-in-swiftui-list-as-sections/70385924#70385924) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121593/shape-data-from-core-data-into-plottable-format/69131192#69131192) might help

Comment: OK that worked! Thank you so much for the suggestion, both of you!