# How to sort an array using date times

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a model that has a date property and I want to be able to sort an array of the model using the date property. It is for a reminder app so I should be able to click a button like today and it will filter the array of all reminders to only the ones with a date before 12am. Any help on how to do this would be great!

---

Reminder Model

```
extension Reminder {
    enum RemindPriority: String, CaseIterable {
        case High
        case Medium
        case Low
        case None
        var name: String {
            switch self {
            case .High: return "!!!";
            case .Medium: return "!!";
            case .Low: return "!";
            default: return ""
            }
        }
    }
    enum FilterType {
        case today, future, all
    }
}
```

---

```
import Foundation

struct Reminder: Identifiable {
    var title: String
    var notes: String?
    var date: Date?
    var time: Date?
    var theme: Theme
    var iscomplete: Bool
    var priority: RemindPriority
    let id: UUID
    // let filter: FilterType
    init(title: String, notes: String? = nil, date: Date? = nil, time: Date? = nil, theme: Theme, iscomplete: Bool = false, priority: RemindPriority = .None, id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.title = title
        self.notes = notes
        self.date = date
        self.time = time
        self.theme = theme
        self.iscomplete = iscomplete
        self.priority = priority
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

---

ReminderViewModel

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var reminds: [Reminder] = Reminder.sampleReminders
    @Published var todayReminds: [Reminder] = Reminder.sampleReminders
    @Published var newRemindData = Reminder.Data()
    @Published var compReminds: [Reminder] = []
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    // init(reminds: [Reminder]) {
    //     self.reminds = reminds
    // }
    func newReminder() {
        let newRemind = Reminder(data: newRemindData)
        reminds.append(newRemind)
        newRemindData = Reminder.Data()
    }
    func deleteReminder(remind: Reminder) {
        Just(remind)
            .delay(for: .seconds(0.25), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { remind in
                if remind.iscomplete {
                    self.removeRemind(remind: remind)
                }
                if !remind.iscomplete {
                    
                    self.removeRemind(remind: remind)
                }
                self.reminds.removeAll { $0.id == remind.id }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    func appendRemind(complete: Reminder) {
        compReminds.append(complete)
    }
    func removeRemind(remind: Reminder) {
        compReminds.removeAll() { $0.id == remind.id }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not as straightforward of a thing as you may think. Here is [an answer relative to displaying Core Data entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70387553/7129318) in a sectioned list. The difficulty in this type of sort is knowing what you are going to be using it for. If for display, you would go one way, and if for computations, another.

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name your enumeration cases starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Hi Lance ! 
if you could provide more info regarding the type of filter you are using. 
Is it like This week, Last week, This month, Last Month and others?

Comment: @NikeshHyanju I just want the filter to be able to filter reminders based on the date. The filter options I want should filter between reminders for today, in the future, and all reminders.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something simple like this approach, using 2 functions, `onThisDate` and `inThisRange` to "...filter the array of all reminders to only the ones with a date before 12am..." :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let testDate1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1234567)
    let testDate2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 7891011)
    let today = Date()
    
    @State var reminders: [Reminder] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text(testDate1.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))) {
                    ForEach(onThisDate(testDate1)) { reminder in
                        Text(reminder.title)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text(testDate2.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))) {
                    ForEach(onThisDate(testDate2)) { reminder in
                        Text(reminder.title)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("today")) {
                    ForEach(onThisDate(today)) { reminder in
                        Text(reminder.title)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("between testDate1 and testDate2")) {
                    ForEach(inThisRange(startDate: testDate1, endDate: testDate2)) { reminder in
                        Text(reminder.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // sample data
            reminders = [Reminder(title: "title-1", notes: nil, date: testDate1, time: Date(), theme: "test", iscomplete: false, priority: .High, id: UUID()),
                         Reminder(title: "title-2", notes: nil, date: testDate1, time: Date(), theme: "test", iscomplete: false, priority: .High, id: UUID()),
                         Reminder(title: "title-3", notes: nil, date: today, time: Date(), theme: "test", iscomplete: false, priority: .High, id: UUID()),
                         Reminder(title: "title-4", notes: nil, date: testDate2, time: Date(), theme: "test", iscomplete: false, priority: .High, id: UUID())]
        }
    }
    
   func onThisDate(_ thisDate: Date) -> [Reminder] {
      return reminders.filter{
         return $0.date == nil ? false : Calendar.current.isDate($0.date!, equalTo: thisDate, toGranularity: .day)
     }
  }

func inThisRange(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> [Reminder] {
    return reminders.filter{
        return $0.date == nil ? false : startDate...endDate ~= $0.date!
    }
}
    
}
```

Note: there are also a number of pre-defined functions in `Calendar`, such as `Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(date: aDate)` that you can use.