# SwiftUI - Core Data error logs flooding console

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a simple view that displays a list of sorted and filtered items. I'm using `FetchRequest` to retrieve the items from Core Data and a computed property to return the filtered and sorted results. (Note I can't leverage `sortDescriptors` here because I'm sorting on a calculated value.)

Here's a snippet from the code:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

private var listItems: [Item] {
    items
        .filter(listFilter)
        .sorted(by: sortType.sort)
}
```

In my list, if I reference `items` directly, all is good but if I reference `listItems`, the console is littered with the following logs:

> CoreData: fault: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault

My understanding is that this error typically appears when you reference an object off the context queue so I tried wrapping the `listItems` calculation in a `performAndWait` on the first item's context but that did not resolve the issue.

What is the solution here?

Comment: It might be best to just use `NSPredicate` and `NSSortDescriptor`

Comment: Unfortunately a Core Data fetch request can't sort on a computed property, only on persistent stored properties.

Comment: that statement is not correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384263/grouping-coredata-by-date-in-swiftui-list-as-sections/70385924#70385924 All you have to do is add `@objc`

Comment: Hmmm I just tried this `@objc var transientAmount: NSDecimalNumber {}` but got the following error: 'keypath transientAmount not found in entity Item'

Comment: Did you put it in an extension for Item?

Comment: I created my Item managed object class manually so I put it in there. Here's the [class](https://pastebin.com/aSpDqU2J)