# Finding transactions total filtered by dates in range in CoreData

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, ordereddictionary

Thank you everyone in advance. I'm new to **SwiftUI**. I am trying to find transactions total for dates filtered with `CoreData` fetch sectioned by month showing month by name sales total as section header for that month when grouping transactions by month.

Transaction entity has name, date and amount attributes. How can calculate sum for each month inside `groupTransactionsByMonth` function for header label of section in ViewModel.
here is my codes for it

```
typealias TransactionGroup = OrderedDictionary<String, 
[Transaction]>

class: ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var transactions = [Transaction]()

    func groupTransactionsByMonth()->TransactionGroup{
        guard !transactions.isEmpty else {return[]}
        let groupedTransactions = Transaction(grouping: transactions, by: {"\ ($0.date?.formatted(.dateTime.year().month(.wide)) ?? "")"})
        return groupedTransactions
    }
}
```

I tried this inside of `groupTransactionsByMonth` function:

```
for(_, value) in groupedTransactions{
    var total: Double = 0
    for transaction in value {
        total += transaction.amount
        return total
    }
}
```

But it gives an error

> Cannot convert return expression 0f type "Double" to return type
> 'TransactionGroup (aka 'OrderedDictionary<String,
> Array>')

```
@Edit1

at moment I am showing my transactions in forEach as following
@ObservedObject private var vm = ViewModel()
ForEach(Array(vm.groupTransactionsByMonth()), id: \.key){month, 
transactions in
Section{
  ForEach(transactions){transaction in
     ReportCellView(date: transaction.date ?? Date(), name: 
transaction.name ?? "", amount: transaction.amount)
                } 
            } header { 
     HStack { Text(month)
              Spacer()
             //here I wanna show monthly total amount for 
posted month in section header not achieved yet
              //Text(" Sales")
              //Text("\(monthlyTotalSalesAmount)")
         }
```

Comment: please. write code in proper format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping CoreData by Date() in SwiftUI List as sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384263/grouping-coredata-by-date-in-swiftui-list-as-sections)

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming this is what your data structure looks like, adapt as needed
struct Transaction {
  let name: String
  let date: Date
  let amount: Double
}

// tuples for transactions & sum
typealias TransactionGroupByMonth = Dictionary<String, (transactions: [Transaction], sum: Double)>


class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
  @Published var transactions = [Transactions]()
  
  func groupTransactionsByMonth() -> TransactionGroupByMonth {
    let groupByMonth = Dictionary(grouping: self.transactions) { transaction -> String in
      return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: transaction.date).month!.formatted()
    }

    return groupByMonth.reduce([:]) { partialResult, item in
      var result = partialResult
      result[item.key] = (transactions: item.value, sum: item.value.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1.amount }))
      return result
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

```
let instance = ViewModel()
instance.transactions = [
  Transaction(name: "1", date: Date(), amount: 0.1),
  Transaction(name: "2", date: Date(), amount: 0.2),
  Transaction(name: "3", date: Date(), amount: 0.3),
]
let grouped = instance.groupTransactionsByMonth()
print(grouped)

/**
pseudo output structure:
{
  "11": {
    "transactions": [Transaction...],
    "sum": 0.6
  }
}
**/
```

I hope you don't have thousands of Transactions cause this isn't the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Can you help me how to implement your way to fix my ForEach for showing transactions or adding sum into my groupTransactionsByMonth() function. i tried to fix it myself but not succesfull. i am amazed by online community help but not much sample for my case. Thanks again – @mani
Bat