# How to create a BarChart from fetched data from CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, charts

I'm trying to create a barchart from fetched data from a CoreData model.
I'm trying to use https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView in particular the release v1.5.5.
The request returns me from the database an array of Entities, let's say its [Entity]. (Entity has two attributes a date and an Int64)
I want to use this data to create the barchart with the labels created by like the example on the github readme :

`BarChartView(data: ChartData(values: [("2018 Q4",63150), ("2019 Q1",50900), ("2019 Q2",77550), ("2019 Q3",79600), ("2019 Q4",92550)]), title: "Sales", legend: "Quarterly") // legend is optional`

In Particular the init of ChartData I wanna use is `public init<N: BinaryInteger>(values:[(String,N)])`

Now I tried to map (using .map() ) the array that the fetchRequest gives to me but unsuccessfully.
How do I transform the data from the array,  into the required signature of the init of ChartData ?
Or do you have any other suggestion in order to accomplish this task, like some order packages I could use instead of the one mentioned before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shape data from core data into plottable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121593/shape-data-from-core-data-into-plottable-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `ChartData(values: fetchRequestResult.map { ("\($0.date)", $0.int64value) }?`
Regarding other libs, you should have a look into `Charts`. It's in more wide known and used by a lot of apps

Comment: Oh my, I tried in anyway possible to map it correctly but I didn't use "(\(..))"
Thank you so much, It worked.

Comment: Since your answer, Apple has announced their Charts framework. So to avoid the inevitable confusion, can we safely assume that you are recommending Daniel Gindi's Charts on GitHub? Apple's Charts also has bar charts, so another option.