# How to prepare CHART DATA?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, charts

> HI ,
> have an APP where i enter readings from electricity meters.
> Now i want to show the consumption in charts.
>
> The readings hold a date, month, quarter and year and the value
> At present I run the values through a ForEach to then sum the values up
> and to create the data series for the chart.
>
> Wonder if there is not an easier way that
> a) prevents the For each
> b) makes use of some nifty Array functions
> c) allows me to use the data from the Entity directly and prevents the detour via the
> Consumption Struc.
>
> Any hint / suggestion would be highly appreciated.
> thx
> thomas

> Data Model:
> ReadingET:
>
> ```
> `@NSManaged public var id: UUID
> @NSManaged public var meterId: UUID
> @NSManaged public var readingDate: Date
> @NSManaged public var readingValue: Double
> @NSManaged public var readingAdjustedDate: Date
> @NSManaged public var readingAdjustedValue: Double
> @NSManaged public var readingConsumption: Double
> @NSManaged public var readingMonth: String
> @NSManaged public var readingQuarter: String
> @NSManaged public var readingYear: String
> @NSManaged public var belongsTo: MeterET`
> ```
>
> `Consumtion Struc:
> struct Consumption: Identifiable {
> var id = UUID().uuidString
> var year: String
> var quarter: String
> var month: String
> var amount: Double
> var date: Date
> }
>
> Data series for chart
> struct SeriesData: Identifiable {
> var id : Int
> var chartLabel: String = ""
> var chartValues: [Consumption]
> var chartValues: [ReadingET]
> }
>
> Build Logic

```
var consumptions : [Consumption] = [] >> Manually filled via For Each
var readings : [ReadingET] = [] >> Filled by FETCH from ET

example for build of Quartely data
similar function for year and month existing

private func getQuarterlyConsumptionByYear(year: Int)-> [Consumption]{
    var sumConsumption1: Double = 0
    var sumConsumption2: Double = 0
    var sumConsumption3: Double = 0
    var sumConsumption4: Double = 0

    readings.forEach { row in
                if row.readingYear == String(year) {
            switch row.readingQuarter{
            case "Q1":
                sumConsumption1 = sumConsumption1 + row.readingConsumption
            case "Q2":
                sumConsumption2 = sumConsumption2 + row.readingConsumption
            case "Q3":
                sumConsumption3 = sumConsumption3 + row.readingConsumption
            case "Q4":
                sumConsumption4 = sumConsumption4 + row.readingConsumption
            default:()              }
        }
    }
let buildData = [
    Consumption(year: String(year), quarter: "Q1", month: "3",  amount: sumConsumption1, date: Date(fromString: "\(year)-03-31", format: .isoDate)!),
    Consumption(year: String(year), quarter: "Q2", month: "6",  amount: sumConsumption2, date: Date(fromString: "\(year)-06-31", format: .isoDate)!),
    Consumption(year: String(year), quarter: "Q3", month: "9",  amount: sumConsumption3, date: Date(fromString: "\(year)-09-30", format: .isoDate)!),
    Consumption(year: String(year), quarter: "Q4", month: "12",  amount: sumConsumption4, date: Date(fromString: "\(year)-12-31", format: .isoDate)!)
        ]

self.consumptions = buildData
return consumptions

}`
```

Comment: Look into SectionedFetchRequest you can have it do the grouping for you. At a quick glance you can use the quarters as sections and then “reduce” to get the total.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shape data from core data into plottable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121593/shape-data-from-core-data-into-plottable-format)