# counting the amount of attributes saved from core data helper class

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes, initialization, helper

In my swift code below the goal is to get the amount of core data attributes saved into core data. I am receiving the error message **No exact matches in call to initializer** at **indexBox.text = String(info?)**. I don't know what to do next.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   let info = CoredataHandler.fetchObject()?.count
        
 
        
            indexBox.text = String(info?)
        
     
        
     
        
    }
}



class CoredataHandler : NSManagedObject {
    class func fetchObject() -> [User]?
    {
        let context = getContext()
        var user : [User]? = nil
        do {
            user = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
            
            return user
            
        } catch {
            return user
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `String(info?)` -> `String(info ?? 0)` ? Since `info` is an optional. But there is a `count` method on the fetch which is faster than really fetching the elements (if you don't use them, but just want to get the count). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134289/cocoa-core-data-efficient-way-to-count-entities

Comment: @Larme I checked the link none of those solutions worked for my project. Can you help me out?